# Are cloud page and landing page same?

Tags: cloudpage, landing-page

Are cloud page and landing page same or is there any difference between them ?

Comment: what do you mean by cloud and landing page? what you are ref ? please elaborate little bit more to you question so others can understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

[CloudPages is an application within Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5) that can publish to [Landing Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_use_landing_pages.htm&type=5) as well as [MobilePush Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_mobilepush.htm&type=5) and [Microsites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_use_microsites.htm&type=5). MobilePush is used to create and send push notifications. Landing Pages are single web pages and Microsites tie Landing Pages together within the same site map.

> CloudPages is a Marketing Cloud application used to create and publish targeted marketing content to customers across multiple channels.
>
> Use the CloudPages editor to build a collection of content, then optimize your content for distinct mobile, social, and web experiences. Publish content immediately or schedule it to publish later. Then, monitor published content to gauge its performance across each channel.
>
> CloudPages supports publishing to these channels:
>
> - Landing Pages
> - MobilePush Pages
> - Microsites